# Laravel Echo + Pusher Authorization Server Error 500

Tags: laravel-echo, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream, pusher-js

I'm trying to test and learn laravel's broadcasting with echo. But after trying and trying I can't achieve what I want.
It works with public channel channel.
But when it comes to presence channels it doesnt.
For solving error I did:

Increasing php memory limit to 1 GB

I'm using Jetstream and Fortify. Also InertiaJS.

Browser debug authorization headers

[authorization headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxPAs.png)

Got error

```
error: "Unable to retrieve auth string from auth endpoint - received status: 500 from /broadcasting/auth. Clients must be authenticated to join private or presence channels. See: https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users"
status: 500
```

**App.js**

```js
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,
    
});

window.Echo.join(`chat.1`)
.here((users) => {
    console.log(users);
})
.joining((user) => {
    console.log(user.name);
})
.leaving((user) => {
    console.log(user.name);
})
.error((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

**BroadcastServiceProvider.php**

```php
public function boot()
{
   Broadcast::routes();

   require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

**channels.php**

```php
Broadcast::channel('chat.{ida}', function ($user, $ida) {
    if (auth()->check()) {
        return $user->toArray();
    }
});
```

**site.net.error.log**

```
[Sun May 16 10:24:49.754522 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 14900] [client ip:38966] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0, referer: https://abcabc.net/dashboard
[Sun May 16 10:26:31.944725 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 4715] [client ip:39000] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 861929472) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in *sitepath*/private/app_data/vendor/pusher/pusher-php-server/src/Pusher.php on line 840, referer: https://abcabc.net/dashboard
[Sun May 16 10:26:31.954042 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 4715] [client ip:39000] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 861929472) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0, referer: https://abcabc.net/dashboard
[Sun May 16 10:27:12.115963 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 19725] [client ip:39026] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 394264576) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in *sitepath*/private/app_data/vendor/pusher/pusher-php-server/src/Pusher.php on line 840, referer: https://abcabc.net/dashboard
[Sun May 16 10:27:12.120752 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 19725] [client ip:39026] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 394264576) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0, referer: https://abcabc.net/dashboard
[Sun May 16 10:30:19.624249 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 14898] [client ip:39066] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 710934528) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in *sitepath*/private/app_data/vendor/pusher/pusher-php-server/src/Pusher.php on line 840, referer: https://abcabc.net/dashboard
[Sun May 16 10:30:19.636461 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 14898] [client ip:39066] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 710934528) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0, referer: https://abcabc.net/dashboard
[Sun May 16 10:30:38.961347 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 14898] [client ip:39086] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 551550976) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in *sitepath*/private/app_data/vendor/pusher/pusher-php-server/src/Pusher.php on line 840, referer: https://abcabc.net/dashboard
[Sun May 16 10:30:38.963699 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 14898] [client ip:39086] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 551550976) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0, referer: https://abcabc.net/dashboard
[Sun May 16 10:31:03.040755 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 14897] [client ip:39104] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 276824064) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in *sitepath*/private/app_data/vendor/pusher/pusher-php-server/src/Pusher.php on line 840, referer: https://abcabc.net/dashboard
[Sun May 16 10:31:03.049553 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 14897] [client ip:39104] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 276824064) (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0, referer: https://abcabc.net/dashboard
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who have this problem look to laravel event classes. Misconfiguration.

Comment: Could you share more about what the misconfiguration was?

Comment: I checked the event classes and I saw that some of them was missing and some of them have wrong class names.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and I resolved it by creating an authentication route and controller. Have a look at my solution in this post: [What can I do to resolve this pusher error-JSON returned from auth endpoint was invalid, yet status code was 200?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67925862/what-can-i-do-to-resolve-this-pusher-error-json-returned-from-auth-endpoint-was/67935290#67935290).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but my private channel was working and my presence channel always got 500 error.

this solved my problem
inside routes/channels.php
adding the 3rd argument

```
Broadcast::channel('channel', function () {

// ...

}, ['guards' => ['custom-guard']]);
```

adding a custom guard that returned user model